# Initialize numba guvectorize output array to zero

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I am trying to create a guvectorize function that iterates over data and changes the value of cells in the output matrix as it goes.  The trouble is, when nopython=True, I can't get the output matrix to initialize to zero, and the output ends up containing nonsensical numbers.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import guvectorize

@guvectorize(['void(float64[:], float64[:], int8[:])'], '(n),(n)->(n,n)', nopython=True)
def test(array_1, array_2, res):
    res[:] = 0
    for i in range(array_1.size):
        if array_1[i] > 1:
            res[i] += 1

a = np.float64(np.random.randint(0, 2, (6)))
b = np.float64(np.random.randint(0, 2, (6)))
c = test(a, b)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[   0    3 -126    4    0    0]
 [   0    0    0   53   26    2]
 [   0    0    0    0    0   53]
 [   0    2    0    0    0    0]
 [   0   59   33    2    0    0]
 [   0    0   56   91   58   93]]
```

This gives the correct output when nopython=False, but then I lose a huge amount of processing speed.

I can remedy the problem with iteratively initializing to zero at the beginning of the code (in place of res[:]):

```
for i in range(unique_years.size):
    for j in range(window_sizes.size):
        res[i, j] = 0
```

but this seems unpythonic and possibly slower than a simple cast.  Using res[:, :] raises a casting error.

Comment: I'm confused by your example code since `array_2` isn't used and in your test function you are only passing 2 of 3 arguments. Also guvectorize functions don't return results, they only populate `res`. Can you please post a working example?

Comment: Is this the code you actually use? I don't quite see how it can create the sample output. Also, it won't compile on my system. After fixing `int8[:, :]` it does not complain about `res[:] = 0` and seems to work fine. That said, you probably don't need to worry about loops in numba. They are considered "unpythonic" because loops can be slow in plain python. However, numba-compiled loops can be almost as fast as numpy built-ins.

Comment: You worry about a `nopython=True` solution is `unpythonic`?

Comment: You also initialize the input arrays with values of 0 and 1, and then check if any value is larger than 1, which will never happen, so the loop doesn't compute anything. I would also make assigning the slice explicit, since `res[i] += ` for a 2d array isn't very clear, why not use `res[i,:] +=` instead?